# sinch push notification error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, sinch

I have a problem with the push notifications, sometimes it's never received and some other times it's received but too late and sometimes I have to send another message in order for the receiver to receive all the messages that never reached him, it doesn't have a pattern or cause (it happens any time or sometimes when I don't use my application for a long time).

I use sinch `managed push` as following:

in my service:

```
private void startSinchClient(String id, String userName) {
        mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(id).
                applicationKey(APP_KEY).applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

        mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);

        mSinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
        mSinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
        //mSinchClient.setSupportPushNotifications(true);
        mSinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);

        //mSinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);
        //mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        //mSinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();

        mMessageClient = mSinchClient.getMessageClient();
        mMessageClient.addMessageClientListener(this);

        mCallClient = mSinchClient.getCallClient();
        mCallClient.addCallClientListener(this);

        mSinchClient.checkManifest();
        mSinchClient.start();
    }

    public void relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(Intent intent) {

                DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(SinchClientService.this);
                UserInfo info = handler.getUserDetails();

                if (mSinchClient == null) 
                    startSinchClient(String.valueOf(info.uid), info.name);

                NotificationResult result = mSinchClient.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(intent);

                if(result.isCall() && result.getCallResult().isTimedOut())
                    return;

                if(result.isMessage() && result.isValid())
                    mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();

                else if(result.isMessage() && !result.isValid())
                    return;
            }
```

GCM broadcast receiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

GCM intent service:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService implements ServiceConnection {
    private Intent mIntent;
    //private ExecutorService mExecutorService;
    //private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (SinchHelpers.isSinchPushIntent(intent)) {
            mIntent = intent;
            connectToService();
        } else {
            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    private void connectToService() {
        getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(GcmIntentService.this, SinchClientService.class), GcmIntentService.this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
       if (mIntent == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (SinchHelpers.isSinchPushIntent(mIntent)) {
            SinchClientService.MessageServiceInterface sinchService = (SinchClientService.MessageServiceInterface) iBinder;
            if (sinchService != null) {
                sinchService.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(mIntent);

                // handle result, e.g. show a notification or similar
            }
        }

        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(mIntent);
        mIntent = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
    }
}
```

I need to know if this is an error with GCM (it terminates connection after a while) or am I doing something wrong in my code.

Comment: It seem the problem is in notification sender, please add notification sender code.

Comment: @Fred as I mentioned, I'm using sinch managed push and they manage sending data to other devices

Comment: Can you try and use a different username, sometimes dev mode when you install and uninstall the device with the same username it can be a bit slow with push becuase you end up haveing alot of instances for the same user.